# Swap or Swop? Which do you use? Is one preferred or correct as opposed to the other or are both equally valid?

Tags: orthography

I see that there was some mention of this on this site 4 years ago.
I am quite surprised to see that 'swap' appears to be the ordinary or dominant spelling
and that 'swop' is a variant. In South Africa we have never used 'swap', to my knowledge at least, always 'swop'.."Let us swop shirts." for example.
The closest i could come to 'swap' would be the word 'swat', To swat a fly.
Any comments on standard usage in your country?

Comment: Thanks for all the comments, very interesting seeing your replies.